# Getting post terms inside PHP class

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a plugin to create a few duplicates for me. I need to duplicate a post which has categories from custom taxonomy. I send a new name with a form and i have the id of the post i want to duplicate. Now when i try to get the terms I get an error `Invalid taxonomy`. The taxonomy is defined and when i `print_r()` it in the file where the form is i get them but when i try to access them in my class i get the error. Can anyone explain why i can't access the post's terms in a class and how should i do it?

Here is a quick example:

```
<form method="post" action="action_file.php">
            <label>New Plot Name</label>
            <br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Plot Name" name="plot_title" />
            <br />
            <button type="submit" name="generate">Generate</button>
</form>
```

And in my class

```
class CustomDuplicator
{

    function __construct(){
        add_action('init', array($this, 'initFunctions'));
    }

    function initFunctions()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['generate'])) {
            $this->duplicatePage(id, title);
        }
    }


    // Duplicate a Page
    function duplicatePage($page_id, $page_title) {
        $old = get_post($page_id);
        print_r(get_the_terms($page_id, 'taxonomy_name')); // -> Here is where i get the error
        $page = array(
            'post_title' => $page_title,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => $old->post_type,
            'post_content' => $old->post_content,
            'post_author' => 1
        );
        $newId = wp_insert_post($page);
        $data = get_post_custom($page_id);
        foreach($data as $key => $values) {
            foreach($values as $value) {
                add_post_meta($newId, $key, $value);
            }
        }
        return $newId;
    }


}
```

NOTE: I successfully duplicate a post but the terms are missing.

Comment: How does this work when you don't have variables for params?  `$this->duplicatePage(id, title);`

Comment: @gview I have i just added them in for context. Edit: Everything is working fine in my code i made a quick example for context only.

Comment: How are you passing `id` and `title` ? How are they getting to your function? What is `$page_id` It doesn't look like from your class that it is defined.

Comment: @HowardE If you read the comment above and my actual post you will see that i just set this class up as a markup of mine so people can understand the context easier. I said i can already duplicate the post I just can't get the terms inside the class.

Comment: How can people help you if they don't know how you're passing the postid to get terms.